# Chaining joinedloads in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to dynamically adjust depths of joined loads of objects in SQLAlchemy.

```
    @staticmethod
    def _get(session, identifier: int, depth=5):
        return session.get(
            Node, identifier,
            options=[
                joinedload(Node.parent).joinedload(Node.parent),
                joinedload(Node.children).joinedload(Node.children)
            ]
        )
```

For this reason I tried to use `getattr` to call chain attributes dynamically. But it fails.

```
>>> joinedload(Node.parent).joinedload(Node.parent)
<sqlalchemy.orm.strategy_options.Load object at 0x7fde0987f380>
>>> 
>>> getattr(joinedload(Node.parent), 'joinedload(Node.parent)')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Load' object has no attribute 'joinedload(Node.parent)'
>>>
```

I do not understand why it fails when I use `getattr`.